# What parameters should we pass to userFriendlySelector function in order to get stream information

Tags: java, api, clearcase-ucm

This query is related to Rational Clear Case Cm api programming using a java. We have a requirement wherein we want to get the list of modified files of a particular stream and in order to do this  we want to get the activity list from Ucm Vob object which we have got from Clear Quest. We are trying to get the stream information using the below mentioned function:-

```
StpLocation streamLoc = provider.***userFriendlySelector(Domain.CLEAR_CASE, Namespace.STREAM,login+"Auto.03.38.00.00.dev.stream","AlnCode_09_PVOB")***;
```

But by doing this we are getting the below mentioned error:-

> CRVAP0226E (internal-error):  Internal error: Status 500; Condition null; Message: CRVSV0135E Internal error: bad length.

What parameters should we pass  to userFriendlySelector function in order to get the required result?

Comment: What ClearCase version are you using?

Comment: OK. I was seeing that kind of error, but those were supposed to be fixed in 7.1.1, so not applicable to your case.

Comment: ok..any idea on which parameters to be used in userfriendlyselector function to get the stream details?

Answer (score 0):

I only know about [the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.team_api.doc/topics/c_addtl_info_location.htm) and [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/rational/r-cn-cmapiclearcaseucmfileoperation/):

```
public CcStream getUcmStream( String streamName ) throws Exception {
     // 获得资源和代理对象 (Access to resources and the proxy object)
 StpLocation streamLoc = m_provider.userFriendlySelector(
 Domain.CLEAR_CASE ,
         // 命名空间类别是流 (Namespace category is stream)
 Namespace.STREAM ,
         // 流名称，传入参数 (Stream name, passed as a parameter)
 streamName ,
         // VOB 标签，构造器中被初始化 (vob tag, initialized in the constructor)
 m_pvobTag) ;

 return m_provider.ccStream(streamLoc) ;
}
```

Depending on the platform, the Vob tag might vary from `\myvob` to `/vobs/myvob`, so check your Vob tag parameter.
And check the stream name: it usually does not include your login (unless it is a development stream named after a user)